# string splitting based on delimiters

Tags: regex, r

My string is

```
 c("closely-monitored",  "rights-of-way", "THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT")
```

I like to split this to separate words as

```
  "closely" "-monitored", "rights", "-of", "-way", "THIS", "_IS", "_A", "_CONSTANT"
```

Tried

```
 paste("\\-", strsplit(str3, "_|-"))
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with perl-compatible regex:

```
vec <- c("closely-monitored",  "rights-of-way", "THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT")

unlist(strsplit(vec, "(?<=[^-_])(?=[-_])", perl = TRUE))

# [1] "closely"    "-monitored" "rights"     "-of"        "-way"      
# [6] "THIS"       "_IS"        "_A"         "_CONSTANT"
```